# EAGLE - Suddenly getting errors about "objects extend outside board space"

Tags: eaglecad, error

Eagle 9.6.2 Standard License
Windows 10 64 bit.

Very strange.  Suddenly I'm getting an error whenever I try to place components in any quadrant but quadrant 1.  I am dead in the middle of a project where I have all my boards centered on my origin (my preference).  I had not problem constructing these boards placing components wherever I needed.

Just an hour ago, I open Eagle and suddenly I can ONLY place components in the positive/positive quadrant and I can't even edit my previously built boards.

My Standard eagle license seems to be in good order and my file name says "Eagle Standard" in it, so I don't think I reverted  to the free version in any way.  I'm totally stumped.

Comment: While I don't have Eagle (use Protel instead) I did have a similar problem ages ago, somewhere in a hidden "ini" file there will be definition of the panel that your design will be placed onto, it might for example be 36" square with origin at the centre, this panel dimension is necessary to later convert your file into a gerber file. The dimensions of your drawing space will be different (i.e. smaller) than this, and your origin will be typically in the bottom left hand corner.  If the definition of the panel dimensions gets corrupted then components won't "stick".

Comment: The above explanation fits your symptoms where all previous PCB's don't work.

Comment: The "only quadrant one is OK" symptom suggest the rotation coordinate is not at the component centre ,
 so instead of rotating , it gets translated by a huge distance as well as rotating.
 Again pointing at some global coordinate definition somewhere.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, @BobT.  This is happening on now on boards I have already completed.  I can't even pick up a component and drop it in the same place if that component isnt' in the positive quadrant

Comment: Ok ,  hopefully someone who uses Eagle can help you out better.  With Protel I made a copy of the "ini" file (it had some other extension) , and desktop shortcut to it. when weird stuff starting happening, I'd poke around in there.

Comment: I had this issue also. The problem with me was my license wasn't properly activated by Autodesk. Send the support an email, they managed to fix it for me.